# Raspberry/docker buildx - how to add another target platforms

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, buildx

I am trying to build an image for linux/amd64 on Rasbbery linux/arm/v7. Unfortunately I can't :(
When I check `docker buildx ls`, I see:

```
NAME/NODE    DRIVER/ENDPOINT             STATUS  PLATFORMS
mybuilder *  docker-container
  mybuilder0 unix:///var/run/docker.sock running linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
default      docker
  default    default                     running linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
```

I went through all the steps explained here: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/. No Idea what to do more :(

Each help is much appreciated